# Use tectonic with a latexmkrc file?

Tags: latexmk, document-configuration, tectonic

Is there a way to tell tectonic to use a latexmkrc file? I could not find anything in the docs.

Comment: surely you mean the other way round? no tex engine reads a latexmkrc. You could use a latexmkrc file to tell latexmk to use tectonic as `latex`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok I'm probably very confused here. I'm using a latexmkrc in Overleaf following https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf#Creating_the_latexmkrc_file. Now I'm trying to compile the document locally, using `tectonic` (which is usually my preferred local tool). What should I do?

Comment: so on overleaf you are running the command `latexmk document`  and `latexmk` is a perl script that runs `pdflatex document` for you.  so if you put `$pdflatex=tectonic` in `latexmkrc`  then it will run `tectonic` instead.  I don't know if that is useful, it depends how close a tectonic log file is to tex log file, whether latexmk can parse it  to decide whether to run again. why do you want latexmk at all rather than just run tectonic directly?

Comment: given that tectonic itself does what latexmk would do, ie decide to run bibtex or re-run to resolve cross references, it would I think be odd (but possible) to use it via latexmk.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! It's clearer now.